# Wordpress Rewrite Rule for URL with tag

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In WordPress I have the following pages:

```
Formation: http://mysite.dev/formation/12345
Messages: http://mysite.dev/formation/12345/messages
Report: http://mysite.dev/formation/12345/report
```

**12345** is a dynamic value representing the formation's id and is actually a query string. I added a rewrite rule like so:

```
function formation_add_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%frm_id%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'formation/([^&]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=formation&frm_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\formation_add_rewrite' );
```

This works fine when I access the page http://mysite.dev/formation/12345, and I can retrieve the query var propery using `$wp_query->get( 'frm_id' )`, but It's not working for the pages with something after the id in the URL.

Is it just my rewrite rule that has a problem, or it simply cannot work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to study php regex a bit. This will prob work (i haven't tested it)

```
  add_rewrite_rule( '^formation/([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)', 'index.php?pagename=formation&frm_id=$matches[1]&SOMETHING=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

note i have matched the second condition into `SOMETHING=$matches[2]`

Basically the operators make the difference here:

- `^` Means match exactly
- `([0-9]*)` = match condition, match a number of any length
- `([a-z]*)` = match condition, match a word of any    length

Comment: Thanks so much, I wouldn't have found it without your help. Here's the final rule:

add_rewrite_rule( '^formation/([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)', 'index.php?pagename=formation/$matches[2]&frm_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );

The other pages are child of the "formation" so this is where I put the $matches[2] condition.